# Why does a method that calls Ping.Send() on an invalid URL die with an unhandled exception?

Tags: c#

The following method calls `Ping.Send()`.  When I pass an invalid URL, Send() dies and an unhandled exception happens.  What is the cause of this?

```
private void ping()
{
         comboBox3.Visible = false;
         listBox2.Items.Clear();

         // check the url if it is null
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text == "")
         {
             listBox2.Items.Add("Please use valid IP or web address!!");
             comboBox3.Visible = false;
             coloring_red_tab4();
         }
         else
         {
             // do the ping 
             coloring_green_tab4();

             for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
             {
                 string s;
                 s = textBox1.Text;
                 string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
                 byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                 int timeout = 120;
                 Ping p = new Ping();
                 PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
                 options.DontFragment = true;
                 //pingexception  was unhalded (if the url wrong here is the error)
                 PingReply r = p.Send(s, timeout, buffer, options);

                 // if it's true url
                 if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                 {
                     listBox2.Items.Add("Ping to " + s.ToString() + "[" + r.Address.ToString() + "]" + " (Successful) "
                       + "Bytes =" + r.Buffer.Length + " TTL=" + r.Options.Ttl + " Response delay = " + r.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms " + "\n");
                     label91.Text = r.Address.ToString();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    // just to know the ip for the website if they block the icmp protocol
                     listBox2.Items.Add(r.Status);
                     IPAddress[] ips;
                     ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(textBox1.Text);

                     foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
                     {
                         label91.Text = ip.ToString();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: You reach the timeout which is an exception.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the code in a `try...catch` and see the exception detail like inner exception or stacktrace?

Comment: @SivaGopal i did it but it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is unhandled because you do not handle it.  Whenever you call a .Net library method, you need to check its documentation to see what exceptions it throws, and decide which, if any, you want to handle at that level of code.  Here is the relevant portion of the documentation for [`Ping.Send()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144956%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which I am including as an image so you will be able to recognize these sections going forward:

[image]

Notice that the documentation states that a [`PingException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingexception(v=vs.110).aspx) can occur if

> An exception was thrown while sending or receiving the ICMP messages. See the inner exception for the exact exception that was thrown.

Thus it's clear from the documentation that many errors from `Ping()` will be reported as thrown exceptions rather than reported by setting `PingReply.Status != IPStatus.Success`.  So you need to modify your code to be something like the following:

```
    public static bool TryPing(string hostNameOrAddress, out string pingStatusMessage, out string pingAddressMessage)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hostNameOrAddress))
        {
            pingStatusMessage = "Missing host name";
            pingAddressMessage = "";
            return false;
        }

        var data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        var timeout = 120;
        using (var p = new Ping())
        {
            var options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            try
            {
                var r = p.Send(hostNameOrAddress, timeout, buffer, options);
                if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    pingStatusMessage = "Ping to " + hostNameOrAddress.ToString() + "[" + r.Address.ToString() + "]" + " (Successful) "
                      + "Bytes =" + r.Buffer.Length + " TTL=" + r.Options.Ttl + " Response delay = " + r.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms " + "\n";
                    pingAddressMessage = r.Address.ToString();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // just to know the ip for the website if they block the icmp protocol
                    pingStatusMessage = r.Status.ToString();
                    var ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostNameOrAddress);

                    pingAddressMessage = String.Join(",", ips.Select(ip => ip.ToString()));
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (PingException ex)
            {
                pingStatusMessage = string.Format("Error pinging {0}: {1}", hostNameOrAddress, (ex.InnerException ?? ex).Message);
                pingAddressMessage = hostNameOrAddress;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I have extracted a utility method from the user interface code and also properly disposed of the [`Ping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance after it is no longer needed.

Then

```
TryPing(@"www.google.com", out pingStatusMessage, out pingAddressMessage);
```

Gives

```
Ping to www.google.com[146.115.8.83] (Successful) Bytes =32 TTL=62 Response delay = 8 ms
```

While

```
TryPing(@"www.kdjf98rglkfgjldkfjgdl;fge8org.com", out pingStatusMessage, out pingAddressMessage);
```

Gives

```
Error pinging www.kdjf98rglkfgjldkfjgdl;fge8org.com: No such host is known
```